# How to sort an multiple array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have created create with a loop,

```
$i=0;
foreach($xml->xpath('//ns2:Soap_Model_SOAP_Hotel_Room') as $rooms)
{
  $room_details[$i]['room_name']=$rooms->name;
  $room_details[$i]['room_id']=$rooms->id;
  $room_details[$i]['room_price']=$rooms->price->value;
  $i++;
}
```

and call this array with another for loop, but the id stored in the array are in shuffle mode, i need to arrange the whole array with assoc mode of my id

currently displaying as

```html
room id : 106556, room price : 22718.65, room name : Deluxe
room id : 106559, room price : 22718.65, room name : Deluxe
room id : 106557, room price : 22718.65, room name : Deluxe
room id : 106560, room price : 22718.65, room name : Deluxe
room id : 106558, room price : 22718.65, room name : Deluxe
room id : 106561, room price : 22718.65, room name : Deluxe
room id : 106562, room price : 31456.62, room name : Club
room id : 106565, room price : 31456.62, room name : Club
room id : 106563, room price : 31456.62, room name : Club
room id : 106566, room price : 31456.62, room name : Club
room id : 106564, room price : 31456.62, room name : Club
room id : 106567, room price : 31456.62, room name : Club
```

I need to sort this array with id, how it possible?

Comment: just use the room id in assigning it then key sort

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php there should be something on here that can help you

Comment: But I need the key value as 1,2,3 mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest assign the room id as key then `ksort` it. After sorting, to reset the keys, just use `array_values`. It'll reset it from `0` index.

```
// assign using room id
foreach ($xml->xpath('//ns2:Soap_Model_SOAP_Hotel_Room') as $rooms) {
    $room_details[$rooms->id]['room_name'] = $rooms->name;
    $room_details[$rooms->id]['room_id'] = $rooms->id;
    $room_details[$rooms->id]['room_price'] = $rooms->price->value;
}
ksort($room_details); // sort by key
$room_details = array_values($room_details); // reassign keys
```

Comment: after key reassign, if the sorting data also reassign?

Comment: @Midhun no it does not, it retains the sorted array

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/function.usort.php) function, if you whiling to compare values of array elements, if you want to use keys (whichs are ids) you can user [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/function.ksort.php)
checkout [what functions](http://php.net/manual/array.sorting.php) you can use to sort arrays and keep same key simultaneously